# HTML/CSS Alpha code &dollar; IE not rendering

Tags: html, css, entity, alpha

I'm trying to use a $ sign in my html page, in which i use the html code below

```
$dollar;
```

Although in IE it doesn't seem to render the dollar sign.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need an HTML entity for the dollar sign since $ is already on your ASCII keyboard. Just type $ (usually as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>).

Anyway, HTML entities start with `&` (ampersand), not `$` (dollar).

Answer (score 5):

You should use the following HTML representation of `$`:

```
&#36;
```

Comment: So he doesn't get hit with possible unicode stuff. Also the fact he is clearly wanting to use HTML code instead of the dollar sign on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no [named entity defined in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) for the `$` sign, but since the character appears in ASCII (and every other character encoding) and has no special meaning in HTML, you never need to use one.

Comment: You should not say "never".  For instance, '$' is a special symbol in maths equations described in LaTeX, and various widely-used plugins exist to allow you to add LaTeX to wordpress pages for example. In these cases you certainly have to use the HTML entity if you wish to show a $ sign in the text.